# FVD format on qemu/KVM

Tags: centos, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

How can I install this format in Centos KVM?. Is it included in latest qemu versions?

Reference in qemu wiki: http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/FVD

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1):

FVD as in "Forward Versatile Disk" ? If so, you need to convert the DVD image to normal ISO first.

If you mean another format, then please elaborate on what you're after

Comment: No fvd is Fast Virtual Disk. Reference: http://wiki.qemu.org/Features/FVD

Comment: never heard of it, which solution uses them?

Comment: There is a patched version here: https://sites.google.com/site/tangchq/qemu-fvd. But it is suposed to be included in qemu mainline

Comment: ah, the new IBM format, I don't think it'll make it into Centos until it makes it into RHEL first. it's easy enough to monitor - just watch the `qemu-img --help` output for fvd to appead

Comment: no but i have been watching qemu source and it is not there to. I think that is a forgotten format

Comment: could be abandoned, I definitely haven't seen it mentioned much. I would stick to raw wherever possible, and use qcow2 when snapshots are required